# Visualization of model of loopback.js application

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to figure out the good way to communicate/visualize domain model of the strongloop's loopback.js application. Swagger is good to understand the REST API, but it is limited only to public entities and shared methods. [Strong-arc/strong-studio](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-arc) is more like a visual model development environment, and probably is not supposed to be used by API clients. Basically, what is necessary is to depict all models, their *relations* and entry points (exposed methods for each of them). Is there any other tool which will better fit this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into LoopBack that does what you want. I suggest using a combination of Swagger with the `common/model/model.json` files (for the model relations). Submit an issue to strongloop/strong-arc with a feature request and maybe they can build something into arc to meet your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this prototype - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-model-visualizer. It builds class diagrams for models.

Comment: Raymond, thanks, looks very close to what I need. I'll definitely give it a try. Couple questions meanwhile. This is for loopback 1.x, will it work as is for loopback 2.x? Also, seems like it is not available via npm, what is the supposed way to use this?

Comment: It should be fine with LoopBack 2.x. You can access it via github for now. We can publish it when it's ready.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.